# How to get the first 2URI only using codeigniter php?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, url

Hi Guys I would like to get the first 2 URI because I don't need the 3rd-nth URIs,

Here's a sample url:

```
http://example.com/news/article/123/crime_is_down
```

And what I need to get are these:

```
Ouput #1: string

news/article
```

---

```
Ouput #2: an array

[array]
(
    0          => ['news'],
    1      => ['article']
)
```

Is there any php codeigniter code for this?

Thanks!

Comment: use explode by slash /

Comment: $url=explode("/",$_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ]);

Comment: $url=explode("/",$_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ]);   print_r($url); echo $url[1]; echo $url[2];

Comment: where it is come from the second output ? how it is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They seem to be controller and method, if so, you could simply use CI's function, like:

```
$this->router->fetch_class(); //gives you controller class name:: news
$this->router->fetch_method(); //gives you method name:: article
```

If you are using CI 2.0.2+, you can do:

```
$router =& load_class('Router', 'core');
$router->fetch_class();
router->fetch_class();
router->fetch_method();
```

Answer (score 1):

use `explode`

```
$url_string = http://example.com/news/article/123/crime_is_down

$url=explode("/",$url_string); 

 print_r($url); 
 echo $url[1]; 
 echo $url[2];
```

OUTPUT:

```
array(
       [0]=>http://example.com)
       [1]=>news
       [2]=>article
       [3]=>123
       [4]=>crime_is_down
    )

    news
    article
```